# Hot standby is falling behind -- how to speed up WAL ingestion rate from `restore_command` in PostgreSQL?

Tags: database, postgresql, backup, wal

We've created a hot-standby machine for a PostgreSQL database that is being pushed to its limit. The main DB is archiving WAL segments to GCS via `wal-g`, and the standby machine is retreiving them with `wal-g`.

Unfortunately, the standby machine is not able to catch up with the main machine! It seems to ingest WAL at the same rate we're producing it (~4segments/s = ~64MB/s). And because our DB is ~5TB, doing a base-backup and restoration always starts us off at least a few hours behind.

So what are some optimizations we can implement to speed up the WAL ingestion on the standby?

The standby machine's disks, network, memory, and CPU speeds should be enough, but we're not using them to their fullest capacity, so there's probably some room for improvement in our `postgresql.conf`.

Comment: Are you more than the 16MB in a WAL file behind? Did you try using streaming replication? Are there replication conflicts?

Comment: Yes, we're thousands of WAL files behind, because the base-backup takes a while. And there are no replication conflicts. Are there any advantages of streaming replication over log-shipping? We haven't tried that yet.

Comment: There shouldn't be any performance benefits in streaming replication, if it is apply speed that limits you. Is one CPU or disk very busy?

Comment: All CPUs stay under 50% and memory is constant at 42.3GB/90GB. Disk writes bounce between 3MB/s-300MB/s. Network reads stay within 50Mbps-100Mbps.